# Criteria for Sequence to Converge to Greatest Lower Bound of Set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a nonempty set $S \subset \Bbb R$ that is bounded below and sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\Bbb R$ which is decreasing. By Completeness of $\Bbb R$, set $S$ has a greatest lower bound in $\Bbb R$.

Intuitively, it seems that if the elements of $S$ are not too far from the terms of $\{x_n\}$, then sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to the greatest lower bound of $S$.

For example, sequence $\{1/n\}_1^\infty\rightarrow 0$ and its terms are a subset of $S = \{x \in \Bbb R: x > 0\}$, but the terms of $\{1-1/n\}_1^\infty$ are also in $S$ but do not converge to $0$.

Is there some sort of criteria which allows us to determine if a sequence converges to the greatest lower bound of a set? That is, if the terms of a decreasing sequence relate to a set in a certain way, then the sequence must converge to the set's greatest lower bound?

EDIT: Without knowing that the sequence has a limit that is $GLB(S)$

Apologies if this is a strange question; I am new to analysis.

Comment: $S \subset \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Are you looking for a necessary and sufficient condition, or only sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the sequence $\{x_n\}$ which is decreasing is bounded below and its limit is the $GLB(S)$.

Here is one criteria which is sufficient:

Suppose, For every $x\in S$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $x_n\leq x$ and for every positive integer $m$ there exists an element $y$ of $S$ such that $y \leq x_m$, then limit of $x_n$ is  $GLB(S)$.

This need not be necessary, as if we consider a constant sequence with limit $GLB(S)$, then we may not satisfy the above unless there is an element of S which is its $GLB$.

However, if we impose the condition that the range of sequence is infinite and that $GLB(S)$ is the limit point of $S$, then the above criteria turns out to be necessary.

Comment: I meant to say, without knowing that the sequence has a limit that is $GLB(S)$

Comment: One criteria is as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Is your criteria supposed to be "nothing but a different way of describing the above statement", i.e.  necessary and sufficient, or do you only mean it is sufficient?

Comment: Answer has been edited.